# Cannot get Intel NUC out of fast boot mode

Tags: bios

I realise this isn't a Linux question, but I'm hoping there's a linux solution.

I have a NUC minicomputer, 7th gen I5 kabylake. At one point I put it into fast boot mode, which means it bypasses looking for F2 at boot time. That was a mistake; now I can't get it out of fast boot mode, so I can't get to the BIOS.

Various websites suggest holding the power button down for 3 seconds when booting. That makes no difference; it boots straight into Mint. Other websites suggest plugging the keyboard into the front usb port and hitting F2 over and over. Same result. There's an HDMI monitor plugged in but all I see are shares of black and grey and then Mint starts to come up, every time.

Does anyone know if there is some way around this? Will it fall back to BIOS if I take the internal disk out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was: I'm an idiot.

The hardware is actually an Azulle Inspire and not a NUC at all. I wish manufacturers would put labels on this maze of twisty little black boxes, all alike.

To get to BIOS on one, hit DEL repeatedly.

I still don't know how to get 8 channel audio out of the HDMI port, but that's another issue.

Answer (score 1):

This really isn't a linux question, but have you considered the [intel KB](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005847/mini-pcs.html)?:

> Fast Boot in BIOS reduces computer boot time. With Fast Boot enabled:
>   You can't press F2 to enter BIOS Setup. USB mice and keyboards are
>   unavailable until after the operating system loads. Disable Fast Boot
>   from the power button menu. Access the power button menu with this
>   sequence: Make sure the system is off, and not in Hibernate or Sleep
>   mode. Press the power button and hold it down for three seconds. Then,
>   release it before the four-second shutdown override. The power button
>   menu displays. Press F3 to disable Fast Boot. See more information
>   about Fast Boot: [...]

Comment: Tried that, doesn't work, have submitted a question to the Intel site.

Comment: Have you made sure that the NUC is actually shut down? `(sudo) systemctl poweroff` should do the trick (if it had `systemd`). If nothing like that works, you could try to find the config jumper and set it to [maintenance mode](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000007242/mini-pcs.html). That should "always" work.

Comment: In my case, there is no F3 option in the menu. There is F2 - it goes to black screen. There is F4 - it just restarts NUC. So there is no way to disable fast boot.